# What happens to a file if I don't store a reference after opening it?

Tags: python, file

When properly using a file object you should either be closing it explicitly with

```
f = open("file.txt")
f.use()
f.close()
```

Or using the `with` method that makes sure the file is closed no matter what

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    f.use()
```

But sometimes I want to grab a file only briefly. Maybe I just want to pull the string out of it and then discard the file. I sometimes write that like this:

```
fileStr = open("file.txt").read()
```

But this neither explicitly closes the file, nor does it use the `with` keyword. Does the file stay opened without any reference tied to it or does Python jettison the file intelligently? And if it doesn't, is there any way I could properly close it? I can't close after reading, as the `close` would be attempted on a string object:

```
fileStr = open("file.txt").read().close()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    open("file.txt").read().close()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'
```